# Google Apps Script не запускается через триггер

Tags: google-apps-script

Не работают триггеры, в чём может быть проблема? Ждал около получаса, функция ни разу не запустилась. [image: Экран триггеров]
При ручном запуске этой же функции всё нормально работает.

Comment: Недостаточно информации для определения проблемы. Например, вы не указываете в каком контексте запускается триггер, в каком контексте вы запускаете функцию вручную. Т.е. при общих прочих равных условиях нет никаких оснований говорить о том, что триггер *должен* отработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общая продолжительность работы функций, запущенных триггером, не может превышать одного часа в день: это один из [лимитов системы Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Если вызывать каждые 5 минут, получается 288 запусков в день, т.е. 12 секунд на каждый (в среднем). Предполагаю, что Ваш скрипт не укладывается в это время. Надо или оптимизировать, или запускать не так часто.

Отмечу, что этот предел (1 час) именно для триггеров, ручной запуск продолжает работать.

Кстати: чтобы убедиться в причине проблемы, достаточно поменять режим уведомлений проблемах с триггером. Этот режим устанавливается в том же диалоге, что и сам триггер. Если заменить стандартную частоту уведомлений (раз в день) на "раз в 5 минут" или даже "немедленно", то причина сразу будет ясна... придёт сообщение с чем-то вроде "Service using too much computer time for one day."